# Unused macro, compiler warning

Tags: elixir, ecto

I've encountered weird issue with the compiler - it claims that my macro is unused despite the fact that I'm calling it in the same module. It may have something to do with using it in where statement but in the end it shouldn't be a problem I guess. Any ideas folks? ;)

```
defmodule Module do 
  defmacrop coalesce(left, right) do
    quote do
      fragment("COALESCE(?, ?)", unquote(left), unquote(right))
    end
  end

  def remove(timestamp \\ Timex.now) do
    Schema
    |> where([p], coalesce(p.time, ^timestamp) < ^timestamp)
    |> Repo.delete_all(returning: select_all(Schema))
  end
end
```

Comment: In my experience, until you know a language well you should always name your variables/functions with a leading `my`.  It prevents headaches like you suffered.

Comment: The thing is I spent a lot of time using Ecto 2.0 and problem appeared after the upgrade ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are not using the macro you defined. You are using [Ecto.Query.API.coalesce](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#coalesce/2)

Comment: Ha! Good catch :) I'm indeed importing `Ecto.Query` here but didn't paste it. Thank you.